# react-native-firestore: Read document ID while creating it

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to save to document ID inside a field in the same document. I'm currently doing it like this:

```
const myDoc = await firestore().collection("users").doc(auth().currentUser?.uid).collection("myCol").add({
  test: "Hello, World!"
});
myDoc.update({id: myDoc.id})
```

Is it possible to do this without having to write to the database 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stated in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8:%7E:text=In%20some%20cases%2C%20it%20can%20be%20useful%20to%20create%20a%20document%20reference%20with%20an%20auto%2Dgenerated%20ID%2C%20then%20use%20the%20reference%20later.%20For%20this%20use%20case%2C%20you%20can%20call%20doc()%3A), for reference, see snippet below:

```js
const myDoc = firestore().collection("users").doc(auth().currentUser?.uid).collection("myCol").doc();

await myDoc.set({
    test: "Hello, World!",
    id: myDoc.id
});
```

This would get the document ID that you would use when adding a document. You need to use the `set()` method instead of `add()` method.

You could also use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to set a custom document ID when adding it in your Firestore Database.